# Can't install python modules + can't fix broken numpy

Tags: python, ssl, libraries

So I'm a science student and I recently bought myself a new computer with Windows 10. I installed anaconda3, pycharm and pyzo for my classes. 
But I have a lot of troubles with the libraries : on both Pycharm and Pyzo, trying to import Numpy (or a library depending on numpy, like pandas) fails with message:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\agnes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.15.4)
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Importing already present modules that aren't linked with numpy works though.
And second issue: I can't install anything ( if I try `pip install turtle` for example I get the same error as previously - whether on Pyzo or Pycharm)
Aand, when I try commands like `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` (all commands beginning with "python"I believe), I get:

```
File "<console>", line 1
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, should I try deleting Anaconda and reinstalling it? Is there some parameter I didn't activate right?

Thank you for helping a poor student who cannot run her code!

Comment: Run `pip install --upgrade pip` in the terminal. Pip does not need to be prepended by python.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by disinstalling again, and reinstalling with a new installer - it was the installer that was broken.